# Extract metadata automatically from excel when uploading a word-file in library

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, excel-import

I have an excel file exported from Drupal with metadata in it (editorname, approvernames, publicationdate, editionnumber, ...). I have a folder with word-files in it, named as the column 'Title' in the excel file (ex A100-00.docx). I've made a library with the same column headers as the excel file. Now I want to fill automatically, when uploading a file from that folder, the metadata in the sharepoint library with the values of the row in excel with the same title as the filename. I'd like to do that in Power Automate and know how to get the properties out of the excel file, but don't know how to find from Power Automate in excel the values of the exact row in the excelfile having the same titlename as the uploaded filename. Somebody can help?

Answer (score 1):

To get the rows data of one excel file in Power Automate, you can upload the excel file into OneDrive, then use "List rows present in a table" to extract the rows data.

There is a blog about this similar topic, for your reference:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Power-Automate-Fundamentals-41-Working-with-List-Rows-Present-in/ba-p/1396653

Besides, Microsoft has a dedicated community for Power Automate, you can also create a new thread on the community for better help:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Power-Automate/ct-p/MPACommunity

Comment: Txs a lot. That's great information for a starter to PA as I am